# pass verbatim arguments to getopts without $@ or $* inside posix shell script

Tags: shell, posix, getopts

I'm trying to pass an argument as "verbatim" to my script, the problem is that the argument in inside double quotes `""` and it starts with a double dash/double hyphen `--`.

This is an example

```
script.sh -f "--conf=bla"
```

In my script both `$*` and `$@` transform this into

```
-f --conf=bla
```

and when this thing reaches `getopts` there is no way to decode this information the way it should be.

And by the way this is my `getopts`

```
foo()
{
    while getopts ":f:" vars
    do
            case ${vars} in 
                    f ) MYVAR=${OPTARG};;  
                    * ) Err; exit 1;;
            esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
}
```

I would like to store `--conf=bla` inside `MYVAR`, I can't find a way to do this, apparently I can't control the way the double quotes are stripped away and, in general, I can't really pass text as verbatim to my script.

How I can control this ?

Comment: Why do you think that presence or absence of the quotes determines the final result here?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it's not really about that, it's about the fact that what I pass as an input it's not what I get once I'm inside the script. The double quotes are just used as a delimiter for the argument the user gives as the input.

Comment: So do you want `$MYVAR` to contain `--conf=bla` or `"--conf=bla"` then?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the first option that you just gave

Comment: And in what way does the result of what you wrote differ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `getopts` gives me an error because the arguments are already stripped before even entering the function `foo` which I invoke with `foo $@` or `foo $*`

Comment: @user2485710 How can `getopts` give you an error before entering `foo` when you run `getopts` inside `foo`?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth please read the question more carefully, or try it yourself, the script is very short, the problem is how the arguments passed by command line are being handled internally by the shell script, anyway my requirement is just about being able to store anything that is passed between `"` and `"` inside my variable.

Comment: @user2485710 Yes, apparently I don't understand your question because your script works as it is supposed to. I will post a test run as an answer, please comment on how this differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/sh

foo()
{
        # unset OPTIND
        while getopts ":f:" vars
        do
                case ${vars} in
                        f) MYVAR=${OPTARG} ;;
                        *) echo "error"; exit 1 ;;
                esac
        done
        shift $((OPTIND-1))

        echo "\$MYVAR=[${MYVAR}]"
}

foo "$@"
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh -f "--conf=blah"
$MYVAR=[--conf=blah]
```

Please elaborate?

Comment: I literally have no idea, I just tried this and it works, this exact thing wasn't working properly 2 seconds ago, I'll try to integrate this in my final script and see if it's everything ok

Comment: wait, in my function I have `local OPTIND` declared before anything else, this could be a problem ? It's the only substantial difference, I forgot that.

Comment: Apparently I was right when writing this the first time, but I probably edited something in the worst possible way, anyway now this works as it is supposed to, thanks.

Comment: @user2485710 `OPTIND` needs to be local to the function where `getopts` is invoked (unsetting it has the same effect), otherwise calling the function multiple times will yield unexpected results. Maybe that is the problem that you experienced initially, but it should have always worked the first time you called `foo`. Anyway, glad it works now!

Comment: but if `OPTIND` is `local` I still need `shift $((OPTIND-1))` at the end of the function ?

Comment: `local OPTIND=1` this is the complete declaration by the way.

Comment: @user2485710 Yes and no, having `OPTIND` reset/local is only needed if you intend to call the function multiple times and the `shift` is only needed if you intend to access positional parameters after your options/option arguments (e.g. `foo.sh -x 1 -y 2 file1 file2 file3`), so technically it's not needed if you don't need to query additional parameters after your options but it's good practice to do both of those things nevertheless.

Comment: but if I declare `local OPTIND=1` at the top and `shift $((OPTIND-1))` at the bottom of my function, there are no drawbacks ? As I understand this, this practice is not needed in my case but it shouldn't harm the script.

Comment: @user2485710 Exactly! As I said, it's good practice wrt/ maintenance, you never know if your script will be adapted later and those are not bugs that you want to hunt down then.